# System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource canceling time

Tags: c#

`System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource` can be instantiated with or without a cancellation period.

```
public CancellationTokenSource();
public CancellationTokenSource(int millisecondsDelay);
```

I use this to attach to an HTTP request.

```
await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(CreateCancellationTokenSource().Token);
```

If I specify a cancellation period to the `CancellationTokenSource`, I know it will be cancelled after that specified time period. I need to know what happens if I instantiate a  `CancellationTokenSource` without a cancellation time period. Will the request never expire if the response fails to return?

Comment: That would depend on the method you are calling. But anything involving the network likely have some timeouts configured at the OS level. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: What is `AsTask`?

Comment: @StephenCleary `AsTask` is used to provide the `CancellationToken`. This is a UWP app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing the expiration time of the http request and of the cancellation token.

So if `CancellationTokenSource` created without timeout, then created via it token will not return `token.IsCancellationRequested == true` until the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` was called.
If you even will explicitly or implicitly call `CancellationTokenSource.Dispose`, then created before token will not be cancelled.

If you want, to have a token, which a priori can't be cancelled, then use **`CancellationToken.None`** as token, it returns `CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled == false`.

Regarding the http request expiration, as wrote in comments there are os timeouts and also `SendTimeout` for httpClient.

Consider also that thread, executing the call can be aborted.

Comment: Thank you. This cleared my doubt. Appreciate it if you can provide me few links to further read on this.